# How do I draw a drawable with its exact size in my custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

**SOLVED: Solution below as answer.**

I have a custom view with a TransitionDrawable and when I draw it in the onDraw() method it scales automatically to fill the whole parent layout, even when it's set in the xml to wrap_content. The picture is in mdpi and hdpi and my testing device (samsung galaxy s) I think it's no more than hdpi.

```
package com.adyrsoft.pronunciationtrainer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class RecordButton extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "RecordButton";
    private TransitionDrawable mDrawable;
    private boolean mActivated;

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListenerInternal = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleState();
            if(mOnClickListener != null) {
                mOnClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }

    };

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = null;

    public RecordButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrib) {
        super(context, attrib);
        init();
    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrib, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrib, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void setState(boolean activated) { 
        mActivated = activated;
        if(mActivated){
            mDrawable.startTransition(300);
        }
        else {
            mDrawable.reverseTransition(300);
        }
    }

    public void toggleState() {
        if(mActivated) {
            setState(false);
        }
        else {
            setState(true);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init() {
        mActivated = false;
        mDrawable = (TransitionDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btnrecord);

        Log.d(TAG, "Drawable intrinsic width and height are: " + 
                Integer.toString(mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()) + " " +
                Integer.toString(mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()));

        mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());



        Log.d(TAG, "The bounds for the button are: "+mDrawable.getBounds().flattenToString());
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
        setClickable(true);
        super.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListenerInternal);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        mOnClickListener = listener;
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying to understand how I should use the drawables in a custom view in order to be displayed in its original size, I've figured out how to do it.

First a few things that I didn't know but are a must is:

1. The background drawable should be left to the parent class to be
   drawn when using View as the parent. If not, the TransitionDrawable can't be seen fading between pictures.
2. Only if I am going to draw on the background drawable I should override onDraw() and do the drawing there.
3. And the last but not less important is that I should override onMeasure() to specify the size of the view. If I don't do it, it will fill all the free space in the parent layout, as it was happening to me.

I've passed the TransitionDrawable to the parent class with setBackgroundDrawable() and since I wasn't drawing in the background drawable, I've removed the onDraw() method. Also I've implemented onMeasure() with a quick and dirty solution specifying the size of the picture I am drawing.

This is the final result:

```
public class RecordButton extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "RecordButton";
    private static final int DESIRED_WIDTH = 180;
    private static final int DESIRED_HEIGHT = 66;
    private TransitionDrawable mDrawable;
    private Rect mViewRect;
    private boolean mActivated;

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListenerInternal = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleState();
            if(mOnClickListener != null) {
                mOnClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }

    };

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = null;

    public RecordButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);

    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrib) {
        this(context, attrib, 0);
    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrib, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrib, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void setState(boolean activated) { 
        mActivated = activated;
        if(mActivated){
            mDrawable.startTransition(300);
        }
        else {
            mDrawable.reverseTransition(300);
        }
    }

    public void toggleState() {
        if(mActivated) {
            setState(false);
        }
        else {
            setState(true);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init() {
        mActivated = false;
        mDrawable = (TransitionDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btnrecord);

        setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);

        setClickable(true);
        super.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListenerInternal);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        mOnClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int m, int n) {
        setMeasuredDimension(DESIRED_WIDTH, DESIRED_HEIGHT);
    }

}
```